# Register JS methods change for CefSharp while updating cefsharp version from v. 57 to version 75.1.143

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

We were using cefsharp version 57.0 in our application and it was working all fine. But now due to some limitations we need to update cefsharp version to 75.1.143 and suddenly our working code broke. One change was to change LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled to true and secondly this line is breaking:

```
browser.RegisterJsObject("objectForCallingServerSideMethods", this);
```

giving error System.ArgumentException: Registering of .Net framework built in types is not supported, create your own Object and proxy the calls if you  need to access a window/Form/Control. Parameter name: value.
It was all working fine. I don't know how to deal with this. Sample code is here which was working before update.

```
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings() { IgnoreCertificateErrors = true, PersistSessionCookies = true, CachePath = LocalFolderPath + "/cache" });
        CefSharpSettings.ShutdownOnExit = true;
        CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true; // added now for version 75.1.143
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("url goes here");

        browser.DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler();
        browser.Width = 0;
        browser.Height = 0;

        browser.MenuHandler = new CustomContextHandler();

        this.Controls.Add(browser);

        browser.LoadingStateChanged += Browser_LoadingStateChanged;
        browser.RegisterJsObject("objectForCallingServerSideMethods", this); // this line is throwing exception now. screenshot is attached.
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is unclear about the exception? You cannot register a Form/Control directly. You should create a custom object,  pass in a reference and call the methods indirectly,  i.e. proxy the calls.

Comment: Can you show me an example? If i would know how to do it i will not post it here.

Comment: You'll have to wait 2-3 weeks if you require an example as I'm effectively on holidays. It's really not that complicated,  create a custom class, move all the methods and properties to your class, if you need to access the form/Control then pass in a reference to the constructor when you create an instance. At least have a go at solving this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sort out its solution. I was passing winform object as 'this' and in version 75.1.143 they have changed the implementation now we cannot use Window/Form/Control. I have created another class named as "BoundObject" and passed its object and it worked as expected.

```
public class BoundObject
{
    // some implementation
    // all methods from JS will be catched in this class. Before this (in version 57) we were receiving these methods from JS on windows form.
}
browser.RegisterJsObject("objectForCallingServerSideMethods", new BoundObject());
```